# Evaluate: $ \lim_{x\to +\infty} {x^3\cos(1/x)\over \sin x} $

Tags: limits

I'm trying to evaluate the following limit but I'm stuck.

$$
\lim_{x\to +\infty} {x^3\cos(1/x)\over \sin x}
$$

I tried the squeeze theorem but I was led to a dead-end. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The limit fails to exist.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have $\sin(1/x)$ at the denominator?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

prove that for any $N>0$ we can find $x_1>N$ such that the function is positive and $x_2>N$ such that the function is negative. So the limit cannot exists.

Comment: It could be $0$ (but it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

We can exclude cos(1/x) as when x approaches infinity cos(1/x) would approach 1. 
Secondly.
We are left with x^3/sin(x). 
If we apply L hospital rule thrice. We are left with -6/cos(x) and cos(x) is not defined when x approaches infinity. Thus the limit is not defined.